# rails 3: Integrating QBO and QBD in rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

---

I want to integrate QBO and QBD in my rails 3.2 application that I am developing. Please help me how to integrate QBO and QBD  API in my web application. I have tried  http://developer.intuit.com and created application there. I have a consumer key and consumer secret also. Now i want to integrate these key to my web application how to do this? Any nice resources or gem...please help me!

Answer (score 3):

Please refer:
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started

There are sample apps also available for .net and java. You can refer them for implementing the same logic in your application.

You can download sample apps from the GITHUB-

https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code

Set your keys in web.config and debug it for more information.

Steps to be followed:

1)Get the opened information for the user using SignIn with Intuit.

2) Then implement Connect to QuickBooks on your home page and redirect to your call back url. Create oauth session and redirect to OAUTH grant url.

3) On the OAUTh grant url page, call AUthorize url - https://workplace.intuit.com/Connect/Begin

4) You will then have the realm id and open id info. The Blue Dot menu will then load.

Comment: Thank you. I have gone through these links. IPP_Sample_Code is for java and .net only. Is there any sample code available for ruby on rails also? I am using connect to quickbook button, will it work for interchanging data from quick book to my app and vice versa ?

Comment: As of now we do not have a Ruby On rails sample app, but we will be working on it sometime in near future.
The Connect to QuickBooks button works using OAUTH to authroize your app to get/send data from/to Quickbooks.

Answer (score 3):

I published a [two-part tutorial](http://minimul.com/get-started-integrating-rails-4-and-quickbooks-online-with-the-quickeebooks-gem-part-1.html) on getting started with QuickBooks integration inside of a Rails app using the Quickeeboks gem.

**Update:** I just added some [more tutorials and screencasts](http://minimul.com/integrating-rails-and-quickbooks-online-via-the-version-3-api-part-1.html) demonstrating integrating a Rails app with the new version 3 QuickBooks API. The previously mentioned tutorial covers the version 2 API.

Comment: you are genius! Thank you so much for that amazing tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I am using quickeebook gem for quickbook integration. It supports lots of features but Quickbook::Online::Job  model is not supported in quickeebook gem. Thats why I am searching for some alternatives.

For learning about quickeebook gem, follow : https://github.com/ruckus/quickeebooks
really nice place to integrate quickbook in rails 3 application